# rotary encoder glitch in arduino

Tags: rotation, android-spinner, arduino-uno, encoder

I hope you can help me with this arduino problem.

I have a rotary encoder hooked up to a servo, and want to achieve that linear relationship of low speed = low angle and high speed = high angle;

It is generally working, this is snapshot from my serial monitor:

> spd = 0
>
> input angle = 0
>
> .
>
> spd = 2863304
>
> input angle = 7023
>
> .
>
> spd = 34
>
> input angle = 10
>
> .
>
> spd = 0
>
> input angle = 0
>
> .

My concern here is that sudden jump to a number such as 2863304, it happens frequently, I'm thinking it is a glitch and I wish to remove it, I would very appreciate it if someone can provide some advice!